# Finding correct solution to this equation

Tags: equation-solving

Consider the equation

```
eq = x == y - Log[1 + y];
```

I would like to solve this equation for `y`

```
yofx = y /. Solve[eq, y]
```

> {-1 - ProductLog[-E^(-1 - x)]}

Unfortunately, this solution seems to be incorrect, as can be verified by inspecting the following two plots

```
{Plot[y - Log[1 + y], {y, 0, 10}], Plot[yofx, {x, 0, 10}]}
```

> [image]

On the left, the plot correctly rises and asymptotes to a straight line for large `y` and `x`. On the right, the plot should have been a flipped image of the left plot, with x- and y-axes interchanged, but the curve looks nothing like it.

Is it possible to get the correct solution for this equation in Mathematica? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: I get a warning from `Solve` that the answer may be wrong. Why not follow the advice in the message?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Using `Reduce` produces an output that still contains an unsolved equation for a constant specifying a branch cut. Instead of trying to solve that equation, I just found by trial and error that the correct branch constant value is `-1`, since the constant must be an integer. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: If you use `Reduce[x == y - Log[1 + y] , y]` you'll get a generalized solution.  Since it seems you are interested in positive values of x and y, you could try `Reduce[x == y - Log[1 + y] && x > 0 && y > 0, y]`, which narrows your solution to `y==-1 - ProductLog[-1, -E^(-1 - x)]`.  If you then plot it using `Plot[-1 - ProductLog[-1, -E^(-1 - x)], {x, 0, 10}]`, you'll get what looks like the axes-flipped version of your left plot.

Comment: @theorist Thank you, that's even better!

Comment: It's worth noting that the inverse function Mathematica provided is the inverse of $y - \ln(1 + y)$ restricted to the domain $(-1, 0]$ rather than $[0, \infty)$.  So it's not *wrong* per se, it's just that Mathematica made an assumption different from yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To plot an equation use [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) or, in this case, [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)

```
eq = x == y - Log[1 + y];

ContourPlot[Evaluate@eq, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {x, y})]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[{eq[[-1]], y}, {y, 0, 10},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}},
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02],
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {x, y})]
```

(* same plot *)

Using your approach,

```
yofx = SolveValues[{eq, y > 0}, y, Reals][[1]] // Quiet

Plot[Evaluate@yofx, {x, 0, 10},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}},
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02],
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {x, y}),
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

(* same plot *)

Comment: Adding a condition `y > 0` and requirement `Reals` to `Solve` is a very nice way to get the result directly, without looking at `Reduce`! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical case where conditional and branch cut check routines are not sophisticated enough to get result, although you give all neccesary conditions (x>0 and y>0 or y<0).

But Solve knows the underlying rules, as can be seen, when you insert numbers for variables (here EulerGamma for x).
Of course you have to check validity of that trick, e.g. with a graphic or insert solution in eq as shown below.

```
eq = x == y - Log[1 + y];

ContourPlot[Evaluate@eq, {x, 0, 6}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   GridLines -> {{EulerGamma}, {-1 - 
    ProductLog[-E^(-1 - EulerGamma)], -1 - 
    ProductLog[-1, -E^(-1 - EulerGamma)]}}]
```

[image]

```
{sol1 = Solve[eq /. x -> EulerGamma, y, Reals], sol1 // N}

(*   {{{y -> -1 - ProductLog[-E^(-1 - EulerGamma)]}, {y -> -1 - 
     ProductLog[-1, -E^(-1 - EulerGamma)]}}, {{y -> -0.729215}, {y -> 
    1.48916}}}   *)
```

Get the two solutions

```
{y1[x_], y2[x_]} = y /. sol1 /. EulerGamma -> x

(*   {-1 - ProductLog[-E^(-1 - x)], -1 - ProductLog[-1, -E^(-1 - x)]}   *)
```

Test it applying Exp to both sides of equations

```
Map[Exp[#] &, {eq /. y -> y1[x], eq /. y -> y2[x]}, {2}] // 
 FullSimplify[#, x > 0] &

(*   {True, True}   *)
```

**Edit**

Most simple way to get solutions, is just apply `Exp`  to both sides of equation.

```
neweq = Map[Exp[#] &, eq, {1}]

(*   E^x == E^y/(1 + y)   *)

Solve[neweq && x > 0, y, Reals]

(*   {{y -> ConditionalExpression[-1 - ProductLog[-E^(-1 - x)], 
    x > 0]}, {y -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-1 - ProductLog[-1, -E^(-1 - x)], x > 0]}}   *)
```